# styles.background_gradient but invers

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

I´m setting a table with pandas styler, but I wonder if is it possible to sort the background_gradient in decreasing way.

Just the contrary of this:

```
.background_gradient(subset=pd.IndexSlice[:6,['Año 2022']], axis=0)\
```

[image: Normal background_gradient way]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asusume you have the following dataframe:

```
   Year  stations  Views
0  2015         1    100
1  2015         2     85
2  2015         3     75
3  2015         4     25
4  2015         5     10
5  2015         6    100
```

You can define a gradient map and then define that it is the inverse of the dataframe:

So, without:

```
gmap = np.array([[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,5]])
df.style.background_gradient(subset=['Views'],axis=None,cmap="Blues", gmap=-df)
```

will give

[image]

while

```
gmap = np.array([[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,5]])
df.style.background_gradient(subset=['Views'],axis=None,cmap="Blues", gmap=df)
```

will return:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. In my case setting map=df['Año 2022']

Comment: the line `gmap=np.array(...)` has no effect in the above examples. The `gmap` used by the method you have directly specified as being related to the the `df`